# How to display the maximum and minimum digits of an integer

Tags: c

I need to find the maximum and minimum digits of an integer.

I tried this but it doesn't do anything:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
  int n,max,min,i;
  printf("Give me a positive integer: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  i=1;
  while(n>=0){
    if(i==1) {min=n%10; max=n%10;}
    else {if(min>(n%10)) min=(n%10); if(max<(n%10)) max=(n%10);}
    n=(int)n/10;
  }
  printf("max. figure:%d  min. figure:%d ", max, min);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Under what circumstances will `i` not equal 1?

Comment: `n>=0` should be `n>0`.

Comment: `while(n>=0)` is infinite loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two issues here:

First, you never change `i` inside of the loop.  As a result `if(i==1)` is always true so you reset `min` and `max` on each iteration.  You need to increment `i` at the end of the loop.

Second, you have an infinite loop.  The test `(n>=0)` will be true if `n` is positive *or zero*.  You want to exit the loop once `n` becomes 0, so change the test to `n>0`.

```
  while(n>0){
    if(i==1) {
      min=n%10; 
      max=n%10;
    } else {
        if (min>(n%10)) 
          min=(n%10); 
        if(max<(n%10)) 
          max=(n%10);
    }
    n=(int)n/10;
    i++;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks!! I forgot to put "i++" while writing the question. But I couldn't figure out why it didn't  work.

Comment: @David That's why you should **always** copy and paste the code you're having problems with into your question.  Things can get lost if you attempt to retype it.

Comment: @David Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.